# Difference in days between two dates in Impala

Tags: date, impala

I am trying to find a date difference In Impala. I have tried a few options. my most recent is below

`ABS(dayofyear(CAST(firstdate AS TIMESTAMP)-dayofyear(CAST(seconddate AS TIMESTAMP)`

an example of data looks like:

> firstDate:
>   2017-11-25
>   secondDate: 2017-11-30

The solution that I am looking for in the above scenario would be five. The provided code would give me this answer, but the trouble comes in when the first date is in december and the second one ends in January.

> Firstdate: 2016-12-30 seconddate:2017-12-30

with the above code this gives me an output of 358 days,the outcome that I would want to see is 8 days. This code is only looking at what day of the year this falls on, and is not able to consider moving from year to year. I know that there is no datediff function on Impala and I've also tried using just subtraction on the two timestamps but that didn't work either. I have scoured google and have come back empty any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SQL

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(TO_DATE(firstdate), TO_DATE(seconddate));
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: It looks like the datediff function will work if i also use the to_date function and example would be : select datediff(to_date(firstdate),to_date(seconddate))

Comment: @burnsa9 - Glad that you have a solution. I have updated the answer if you wanted to mark it as answer for your question.